# select....for update and if statement with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

Ok, what I have right now is this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT redeemTicketChances FROM userRedeemChances WHERE userId='917' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE userRedeemChances SET `redeemTicketChances` = redeemTicketChances - 1;
COMMIT;
```

What I want to know is if redeemTicketChances is 0.  If it is 0 I do not want to subtract 1 from it.  I also want it to return back to php whether or not it successfully subtracted 1 or if redeemTicketChances is already 0.

I am not great at advanced sql like this so I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE userRedeemChances SET `redeemTicketChances` = redeemTicketChances - 1
WHERE redeemTicketChances > 0 AND userId='917'
```

Comment: .. and add to your WHERE clause " AND userId = '917' " and then check how many rows were updated (seems mysql_affected_rows() in php) to let you know if a subtraction happened or not.